# Magento2: Filter product collection by product attribute

Tags: magento2

How to filter product collection by product attribute in magento 2 like we did in magento 1.x using addAttributeToFilter method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`addAttributeToFilter()` should works like in `M1` on an `EAV` collection and `addFieldToFilter()` on a `Flat` `Collection`

Comment: I wnat to filter start_date and end_date attributes, how you do?

Comment: $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
[
    ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
    ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
]

Answer (score 3):

have to add below functions in your block file and call getProductCollection() function template file

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,

    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
[
    ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
    ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
]
);
  return collection;
}
```

You can also used below code :

```
      if($from != ''){
        $from = date_create($from);
        $from = date_format($from,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from));
    }
    if($to != ''){
        $to = date_create($to);
        $to = date_format($to,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('to' => $to));
    }
```