# Magento2: How to get product collection by attribute or category id?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, collection, attribute-set

How to get product collection by multiple attributes?

Magento 2.0

Comment: Collection by category id -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125086/get-product-collection-by-category-id-on-phtml-file-magento2

Comment: Collection by attribute -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94946/magento2-filter-product-collection-by-product-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

to get product collection and filter by multiple attribute like this:

```
$productCollection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('sku',array('eq' => $styleCode));
```

Use "Dependency Injection" method to implement this, Please reply if need more clarification,

Comment: How to get product collection brand attribute wise on the product view page.

Comment: 1. You can override this Class \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View 
2. Use above mentioned ProductFacory as Dependency injection as $_productFactory
3. Create new function in same class and insert below code in this function:
       $productCollection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('brand',array('eq' => $brand));
    return $productCollection;
4. Now call above created function on product page phtml however that phtml should be linked with above overriden class.

Comment: Hi, om I have tried but it is not getting data.

Comment: can you discuss on chatbox with me?